# RESTful approach on huge filtering query

Tags: json, rest, url, filter

I am designing and implementing a REST endpoint for retrieving and filtering large amounts of data. The data is structured into signals and come from different data sources. The filtering process returns only the specified signals from the specified sources. Two signals from two different sources may have the same name, so they cannot be uniquely identified by name alone.

The question is, what approach would be the most scalable and RESTful?

Things I considered:

1. Make a **GET** request with two lists of parameters in the URL: the signal name list and their corresponding sources (*sources=src1,src1&signals=sig1,sig2*). However, this would result in a very long query string.
2. Make a **GET** request with a JSON body, containing the source names as the keys and the signal names as a vector (*{src1:[sig1,sig2]}*). However, this would break the RESTful good practices, as a **GET** request shouldn't have a body.
3. Make a **POST** request with the body presented at 2. However, I already have a **GET** endpoint for retrieving the data (without filtering however) and I need to use the same. I could change the request to a **POST**, but it doesn't feel right to use **POST** for retrieving data.

Other limitations: new sources may be added later, so I can't just use the source name as the query parameter name (also, I already other query parameters) - but I could easily iterate through a JSON's keys. There are also sources that contain no signals, so I should be able to include them too (the same if, for instance, the client requests all signals from a source). Finally, the signal database contains about 30,000 signals so far, so the worst case should be able to cover all of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid option 2, as you've pointed it it's not a good idea. A lot of API frameworks won't let you do it anyway.

As for the other two options - I don't think there is anything wrong with having a really long URL, it may look ugly but at least you get all the benefits of GET (idempotency, clarity, bookmark-able). Try to get it working with this option and maybe consider some workarounds if possible.

But ultimately don't be too afraid of moving across to POST if you really need to. It's not ideal, sometimes you can't really get around breaking convention.